# { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: Address: call to non-contract", "data":

Tags: solidity, remix

how are you?

```
I have an IDOmaster con`enter code here`tract that I call a function to create an IDO, when I execute the IDOmaster contract it works perfectly, but when I call the function, the Remix always gives me the same error.

I use Remix and perform a web3 inject to deploy them.

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: Address: call to non-contract", "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001d416464726573733a2063616c6c20746f206e6f6e2d636f6e7472616374000000" }

I don't know how to continue


The function has 4 parameters that I have to pass in

Token name, token, symbol, tuple that I paste below and quantity

["0x9cE15ffdb115248137c6578C4f7C28083E8957Bd", "35000000000000000", "1632495600", "1635681600", "10000000000000000", "10000000000000000000", "50000000000000000000", "500000000000000000000"]
```

I can send the code to see if they can see the bug, I don't understand how I can continue.